# Regex does not match text after last match

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I'm trying to get all text but not if it's inside inline code (`) or code block(```). My regex is working fine but the last text doesn't match and I don't know why.

My current regex:

```
(.*?)`{1,3}(?:.*?)`{1,3}(.*?)
```

You can check out the result here: https://regex101.com/r/lYQnUJ/1/

Maybe anybody has an idea how to solve that problem.

Comment: Could you please do mention which language it is you are looking for regex?

Comment: Split with ``"(?s)```.*?```|`[^`]*`"`` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/KDSzPz/1) where the matches are replaced with "---" line). The last part is not matched because the `(.*?)` at the end of your regex does not match any text. If you remove it, nothing will change.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13: Sorry, I've added pcre and php tag.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Do you mean like this: https://regex101.com/r/6aqtVC/1 ? Unfortunately it's the same. Last text part does not match too. :/ Thanks for the hint with the last group which can be removed.

Comment: See ``print_r(preg_split('~```.*?```|`[^`]*`~s', $text))`` at https://3v4l.org/2kO6K. Is the output the one you expect?

Comment: If it is not what you need, please explain your scenario, add the code you are using, add more details.

Comment: And if you have a too complicated case and can only provide the regex as input to some code/function/tool, try ```(?|(.*?)(`(?:``)?).*?\2|((?:(?!`(?:``)?).)+)\z)```, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9iqjXW/2), see the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/phW7F).

Comment: My plan was to run preg_replace_callback() and do some search and replace actions on the non code text. But I like your preg_split() example. It's simple, fast and clean. I think that solves my problem. Thanks a lot @WiktorStribiżew!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

````php
preg_split('~```.*?```|`[^`]*`~s', $text)
````

*Details*:

- ```` ``` ```` - triple backtick
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars as few as possible
- ```` ``` ```` - triple backtick
- `|` - or
- `` ` `` - a backtick
- `` [^`]* `` - zero or more chars other than a backtick
- `` ` `` - a backtick

See the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/KDSzPz/1) and [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/2kO6K):

````php
<?php

$text = 'your_text_here';
print_r(preg_split('~```.*?```|`[^`]*`~s', $text));
````

Output:

```php
Array
(
    [0] => some text here

some more


    [1] => 

some 
    [2] =>  too

and more code blocks:



    [3] => 

this text isn't matched...
)
```